# Simplify the Boolean Expressions (x+y).(x+z)

Tags: boolean, boolean-expression

Simplify the Boolean expression " (x+y).(x+z) " .

I think answer is " x+y.z " But i don't know how t get that.

Comment: I don't think `.` is a valid boolean operator... neither is `=` for that matter (at least not in most languages). What language is this in?

Comment: Yes it is a typing mistake sorry for that but now i corrected that and didn't get answer to my question If you know to solve that please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the De Morgan Law (A+B)=(A'.B'). It works this way: 
`(X+Y)=X'.Y' and (X+Z)=X'.Z'`
By commutativity: `(X+Y).(X+Z)=(X'.Y').(X'.Z')=X'.Y'.X'.Z'=X'.X'.Y'.Z'`
By idempotence: `X'.X'=X'`
Then: `X'.X'.Y'.Z'=X'.Y'.Z'=X'.(Y'.Z')`
Calling: `Y'.Z'=W`
Then: `X'.(Y'.Z')=X'.W'`
By De Morgan: `X'.W'=(X+W) (I)`
Negating the affirmation: `W'=Y'.Z' then W=(Y'.Z')'=Y'+Z'=Y.Z (II)`
By (I) and (II): `(X+Y).(X+Z)=X+(Y.Z)=X+Y.Z`

Comment: `(A+B)=(A'.B')'`, please note the last `'`.

Comment: Is there any name for this identity?

Answer (score 2):

```
(x+y)(x+z) 
= xx + xz + yx + yz 
= x + xz + yx + yz (since xx = x eg 0.0 = 0 , 1.1 = 1)
= x(1 + z + y) + yz
= x(1 + y) +yz (since 1 + z = 1 e.g 1+0 = 1 or 1+1 = 1)
= x(1) + yz (since 1 +y =1 as explained above)
= x + yz
```

Answer (score 1):

`(x+y)(x+z)` -Distribute-> `xx+xy+xz+yz` -x.x=x-> `x+xy+xz+yz` -> `x+x(y+z)+yz` -x=x.1-> `x.1+x(y+z)+yz` -> `x(1+(y+z))+yz` -1+(y+z)=1-> `x+yz`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler solution by using idempotent(`xx = x`) and absorption(`x+xy = x`) laws.

```
(x+y)(x+z) = xx+xz+xy+yz = x+yz
```